# css-mode: use tabs and not spaces

Tags: indentation, whitespace, tabs, css

How do I make it so tabs are used instead of spaces when `TAB` is pressed? I've tried setting `indent-tabs-mode` to `t` but no dice.

On my other modes, such as php-mode and c-mode, tabs are inserted. CSS mode seems to be ignoring.

God I hate spaces so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The built-in CSS mode should support this just fine by giving `indent-tabs-mode` a non-nil value.

Note that spaces will still be used for padding if the number of indentation spaces isn't a multiple of `tab-width`. The default values of `tab-width` and `css-indent-offset` are 8 and 4 respectively, so you'll need two levels of indentation before a tab is inserted.

I think what you want in this case is to set `tab-width` and `css-indent-offset` to the same value.

Comment: `(setq indent-tabs-mode t)`, `(setq tab-width 4)`, and `(setq css-indent-offset 4)` work. This applies to new typing. If four spaces are already there, pressing the `TAB` key does not change the four spaces to one TAB. Also, `indent-tabs-mode` is a variable in `C source code`. `(add-hook 'css-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq indent-tabs-mode t) (setq tab-width 4) (setq css-indent-offset 4)))` in `.emacs` makes it buffer-local. (See `\C-h v`.)

Answer (score 0):

You might be out of luck with the built-in css-mode.el. There does not seem to be anything in the package code that allows using tab characters for indentation.

If you collaborate writing code, you are facing an uphill struggle as most people try to avoid tabs like plague. :)

However, EmacsWiki has (old) code for an other [css-mode.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/css-mode.el) that has customisable variable `css-tab-mode`. Its effect is explained in function `css-tab-function`. You could try if its other features are good enough for you.